# How to center this table cell inside a row?

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

How could I center the single cell inside a tr, is there a property that I'm not aware of perhaps? So, I would like that single cell to be centered no matter how many cells will be added above or below, if that's possible..? This is in the context of an email template.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 50px;  
}

.center {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="center">center me please</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know you will say it's not a duplicate ... but it's as all you have to do is to center the table element using `margin:0 auto`

Comment: yeah, thanks...sorry, using it in the context of the e-mail template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `align="center"` to the `table` which you want to make center

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 50px;  
}

.center {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td class="center">center me please</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: NO : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_align.asp --> **The align attribute of <table> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.**

Comment: @smithy please don't accept this answer and don't use it ... it provides an obselete non supported way to center, refer to the link I shared.

Comment: This is the right/easiest way of doing it if you're building html email

Answer (score 0):

Simple Apply left and right `margin: auto` of the inner table

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 50px;  
}

.center {
  padding: 0;
}

/*Apply left and right margin: auto of the inner table*/
#main table {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="center">center me please</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```